# What does a property of an object is enumerable mean in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, object, for-loop, enumerable

`Object.propertyIsEnumerable` can determine whether an property is enumerable or not. And that means the prop can be enumerated by `for...in`, but properties inherited through prototype chain are not considered by this method.

I am wondering whether those inherited props are enumerable?

```
     var obj1 = {
        'a': 'b'
    },
    obj2 = {};
    var obj2Proto = Object.create(obj1);
    obj2.__proto__ = obj2Proto;
    obj2.c = 'd';
    for (var key in obj2) {
      console.info(key, obj2.propertyIsEnumerable(key))
      // c true; a false
    }
    console.info(Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(obj2, 'a')) // undefined
```

I am totally confused.

Comment: It depends on how the `prototype` objects in the prototype chain defines those properties. Classes methods for example are not enumerable. Also, in your example, `propertyIsEnumerable` returns false because you are checking the property in another object but do notice that `for..in` picks it up because it's enumerable.

Comment: Thanks, it really helps. `propertyIsEnumerable` returns false because `a` is out of its range, rather than `a` is non-enumerable.